# C++ vertical bar?

Tags: c++, operators

What does a vertical bar before an equal sign mean? Like in the code below:

```
 UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;
#ifdef _DEBUG
createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This

```
createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
```

is the compound assignment operator and in fact is equivalent to

```
createDeviceFlags = createDeviceFlags | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
```

where operator | means bitwise operator OR. That is for all bits of these two operands operation OR is applied. It usually used to set on some bits or flags in an integral object.

The action of the bitwise OR operator is following

```
0 | 0 = 0
0 | 1 = 1
1 | 0 = 1
1 | 1 = 1
```

So this statement sets on bits of variable createDeviceFlags that corresponds to set bit of flag  D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG That is this flag is switched on.

Answer (score 5):

The `|` operator is the [bitwise OR operator](http://www.processing.org/reference/bitwiseOR.html).

As with the `+`, `-`, `/`, and `*` operators, placing the `|` operator before the equal sign is a shorthand version of:

```
createDeviceFlags = createDeviceFlags | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
```